# HTML5 Drag and Drop with Save Features

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, save

I know there are plenty of guides on how to create a drag and drop feature with HTML5 but I would like the user to drag a bunch of pre-defined images which are available on a 'sidebar' to create another image then this image to be saved when the user hits a certain button. Any ideas?